# pub get failed Because circular_slider requires SDK version 2.12.0, version solving failed

Tags: flutter-dependencies

I am learning flutter developpment and would like to make an interface using [Sleek Circular Slider](https://pub.dev/packages/sleek_circular_slider)
When I follow the instruction for adding it in my flutter project, I have an error message when I "pub get". Can you help me please ?
The error message:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.9.1.

Because circular_slider requires SDK version 2.12.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because circular_slider requires SDK version 2.12.0, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my YAML file

```
name: circular_slider
description: A new Flutter project.


publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  sleek_circular_slider: ^2.0.1

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: I updated Android Studio (Dolphin and Dart and Flutter), the problem is still here :/

Comment: It's ok, I uninstalled Flutter and Dart from Android Studio, then reinstalled them and I download and extract the last version of flutter, then replace the c:\flutter directory and everything is ok now

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, I uninstalled Flutter and Dart from Android Studio, then reinstalled them and I download and extract the last version of flutter, then replace the c:\flutter directory and everything is ok now